# VisJS Edit Edges: Is it possible to use editWithoutDrag and still be able to move the to/from points of the arrow?

Tags: vis.js, edges

Using VisJS, I need to show up a pop-up to edit properties for an edge.  However, I also need to be able to drag the to/from points of that edge.  I was able to use editEdge's `editWithoutDrag` to show my pop-up, but then I couldn't drag the to/from points of the edge on the GUI.  I'm starting to suspect that it's not possible, but maybe it's just a javascript thing that I don't know how to code.

This works for editWithoutDrag.

```
editEdge: {
    editWithoutDrag: function(data, callback) {
        //pop-up code
        alert("no drag!");
    }
},
```

But I need to be able to use the default to/from dragging of `editEdge` AND the `editWithoutEdge` option.

```
editEdge: function(data,callback) {
    data.nodeAction = "editEdge";

    // how to get editWithoutEdge to work here?
}
```

Any ideas?